# ruby cgi wont return method calls, but will return parameters

Tags: ruby, cgi, return, if-statement

my environment: ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22 revision 39386) [x86_64-linux]

The thing is, I can make ruby return the parameters sent over GET. but when i'm trying to use them as arguements to my methods in if/else, ruby wont return anything and I end up with a blank page.

ph and pm return correctly:

```
http://127.0.0.1/cgi-bin/test.rb?hostname=node00.abit.dk&macadd=23:14:41:51:63
```

returns:

```
node00.abit.dk 23:14:41:51:63
```

Connection to the database (MySQL) works fine

When I test the method newHostName it outputs correctly:

```
puts newHostName
```

returns (which is correct)

```
node25.abit.dk
```

the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'cgi'
require 'sequel'
require 'socket'
require 'timeout'

DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'mysql', :host=>'localhost', :database=>'nodes', :user=>'nodeuser', :password=>'...')

#cgi-part to work
#takes 2 parameters:
#hostname & macadd 
cgi = CGI.new
puts cgi.header

p = cgi.params
ph = p['hostname']
pm = p['macadd']

def nodeLookup(hostnameargv)
        hostname = DB[:basenode]
        h = hostname[:hostname => hostnameargv]

        h1 = h[:hostname]
        h2 = h[:macadd]
        ary = [h1, h2]
        return ary
end

def lastHostName()
    #TODO: replace with correct sequel-code and NOT raw SQL
    DB.fetch("SELECT hostname FROM basenode ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") do |row|
        return row[:hostname]
    end
end

def newHostName()
    org = lastHostName
    #Need this 'hack' to make ruby grep for the number
    #nodename e.g 'node01.abit.dk'
    var1 = org[4]
    var2 = org[5]
    var3 = var1 + var2
    sum = var3.to_i + 1
    #puts sum 
    sum = "node" + sum.to_s + ".abit.dk"
    return sum
end

def insertNewNode(newhost, newmac)
    newnode = DB[:basenode]
    newnode.insert(:hostname => newhost, :macadd => newmac)

    return "#{newnode.count}"
end

#puts ph
#puts pm

#puts newHostName
cgi.out() do
    cgi.html do
        begin
            if ph == "node00.abit.dk"
                puts newHostName
            else
                puts nodeLookup(ph)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I feel like im missing something here. Any help is very much appreciated!

//M00kaw

Answer (score 0):

What about modify last lines of your code as followed? CGI HTML generation methods take a block and yield the return value of the block as their content. So you should make `newHostName` or `nodeLookup(ph)` as the return value of the block passed to `cgi.html()`, rather than `puts sth`, which prints the content to your terminal and return `nil`. That's why `cgi.html()` got an empty string (`nil.to_s`).

```rb
#puts newHostName
cgi.out() do
  cgi.html do
    if ph == "node00.abit.dk"
      newHostName
    else
      nodeLookup(ph)
    end
  end
end
```

**p.s.** It's conventional to indent your ruby code with 2 spaces :-)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out:> 
I'm going to fix the 2-spaces thing..

Removing "puts" from the if/else didn't help. It still doesn't output anything :/

Comment: Take a look in the log file of your cgi server. You might find something helpful there. Or you can try not to rely on the database while debugging, just return some hard-coded string from the `cgi.out()` to see if that works. There might be something wrong with the DB connection.